# How to apply hot code swap functionality as a patch in erlang?

Tags: erlang

I have made several changes in different interdependent files in my erlang project. As erlang supports hot code swapping, is it possible to apply all my changes as a whole patch(all at once) on a live system instead of worrying about compile and function call order. If yes how?

Answer (score 1):

Since Erlang/OTP 19, there are some new functions for atomic loading of a group of modules. See http://erlang.org/doc/man/code.html#atomic_load-1 for details.